# EXC_BAD_ACCESS uint32_t

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I am attempting to implement an extension method on NSData in Obj C. The extension method calls a cpp lib method.

Here is the method signature of the cpp method:

`void process(char *result) { }`

Here is the extension method calling the cpp method:

```
- (NSData *)PROCESS
{
    uint32_t result;

    process((char*)&result);

    // At this point result shows 2949384954 as the value

    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&result length:sizeof(result)];

    return d;
}
```

When I use `PROCESS` and assign the returned (NSData*), I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I'm sure this has to do with improper use of pointers or references, but I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Log result and add it to the question. In hex would be best. When you have a problem break it down to find out exactly where it is. Post eh exact error message, copy and past and any stack trace.

Comment: @Zaph yes. sorry. I come from a .net background.

Comment: Why are you implementing a category, it is generally best to just implement a method of a class. Also by convention method names are camel case starting with a lowercase letter and class names are camel case starting with an uppercase letter in Objective-C.

Comment: @Zaph 0xafcc0afa is what I expect. But when PROCESS returns the NSData* value, it bombs with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: Are you sure process doesn't write more than 4 bytes?

Comment: What does `process()` do? Does it set a string into `result`? If that the case, what didn't you use `char result[<expected_length>]` instead of `uint32_t result` and `strlen(result)` instead of `sizeof(result)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code following code works fine:

```
uint32_t result = 2949384954;
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&result length:sizeof(result)];
NSLog(@"d: %@", d);
```

NSLog output:

```
d: <fa0accaf>
```

There is probably an issue with the way the method is called.

Back to "extension method ". What do you mean by that? Just make this a function to add it as a method to a class.